# Spring Transaction - Log method execution time on new transaction

Tags: java, spring, transactions, profiling, aspectj

I have an aspect-j aspect (weaved at compile time) to log method name and execution time when this last is greater than 1s.

Logs are aggregated in an ELK stack and we would like to make profiling visualisation, the problem is all the subcall in the stack are also traced and we have so multiple traces with multiple method name for each unit of work.

I would like to trace only the entry point method of each unit of work ie. each method triggering a new transaction (and not the one joining an existing transaction).

Is there a way to do so without overriding spring TransactionInterceptor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a simple solution using only AspectJ, the following might work for you.

Let's say you have a named pointcut `transactionalMethodExecution`:

```
pointcut transactionalMethodExecution(): execution(@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional * *(..));;
```

You can exclude all nested `transactionalMethodExecution` pointcuts in the control flow of the topmost one by using [`cflowbelow`](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html):

```
transactionalMethodExecution() && !cflowbelow(transactionalMethodExecution())
```

From the documentation on `cflowbelow`:

> `cflowbelow(Pointcut)`
>
> Picks out each join point in the control flow of any join point `P` picked out by `Pointcut`, but not `P` itself.

This solution is admittedly simplistic, it doesn't handle cases like nested transactions or anything more fancy. You'll need a more thorough solution for those cases.

Comment: I don't have nested transaction (JTA), this seems exactly what I'am looking for ; Simple & elegant ! I'll test and accept a bit later if you don't mind :)